# GET Method returns 404 Error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, http

My project has Hibernate and Spring.

If I do a `GET` `User` from Postman it returns 404 but the other classes return 200. The code of all the classes is the same, I don't know why just `User` returns an error.
In the rest of my classes all the methods (`POST`, `PUT`, `GET`, `DELETE`) return 200 but when it comes to `User` they all return 404.

Here is the code for `Service/UserService.java`

```
public List<UserDTO> getAll() {
    List<UserDTO> userDTOList = new ArrayList<UserDTO>();
    try {
        for (User user : userDAO.findAll())
            userDTOList.add(new UserDTO().convert(user));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
    return userDTOList;
}
```

`UserDao` extends from `GenericDao`:

```
public List<T> findAll() {
    return entityManager.createQuery(
            "from " + className.getName() + "  i order by i.id").getResultList();
}
```

And a part of `UserResource.java`:

```
@Component
@Path("/user")
public class UserResource {

/** other methods**/
        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public List<UserDTO> getAll() {
            return userService.getAll();
        }
}
```

If I do a `GET` at `localhost:8080/rest/travel` it returns `Success 200`, meanwhile at `localhost:8080/rest/user` it returns `404 NOT FOUND`.

Comment: Is your package of the UserResource class covered in the cotext:component-scan in the configuration file?

Comment: I missed it add the userResource context:component .Now i added then work! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring, you should use @RestController instead of @Component, and @RequestMapping instead of @Path